# Filling an array with random numbers from the range [-n, n] using Math.random

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have a function in which I enter the size of the multidimensional array n. Next, I fill this array with random numbers in the range [-n, n], using Math.random ():

```
private int[][] enterMatrixSize() {
    System.out.print("enter matrix size (n): ");
    String input;
    while (!(input = in.next()).matches("\\p{Digit}+")) {
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive Integer: ");
    }
    int size = Integer.parseInt(input);
    int[][] array = new int[size][size];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            array[i][j] = (int) (Math.round(Math.random() * (size + 1)) - size / 2);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++, System.out.println()) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(array[i][j]+" ");
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

But it displays some incorrect values. For example, when I enter n equal to 1 - displays the numbers 0, 1 and 2. Which is strange. Since should output -1, 0, 1

Comment: Replace `size + 1` just with `size` else you shift the random numbers up by `1`, which is why you get the current output

Comment: because round of 1.5 is 2, so in other words supposing random()=1 and size=1 then you have 1*(1+1))-1/2 so (2-1)/2, instead use .floor(x) method

Comment: @vmrvictor Then `Math.floor()` can be omitted completly, the casting to `int` will already discards all the decimal places, which acts the same as a flooring operation

Comment: @Lino not for negative numbers. `Math.floor(-1.5) == -2`, while `(int)(-1.5) == -1`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException You're completly right, my comment even states that: *... will discard all decimal places ...*, so with negative numbers `Math.floor()` must be used. Though why come up with such logic if you can already use the jdk for that `ThreadLocalRandom#nextInt(int, int)` :)

Answer (score 2):

I would change this line:

```
array[i][j] = (int) (Math.round(Math.random() * (size + 1)) - size / 2);
```

to:

```
array[i][j] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( -size, size + 1);
```

to generate a random int value in a specific range, here [-size, size]

Comment: Hm we had the same idea, but you were seconds faster, have an upvote then ;)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `ThreadLocalRandom` which provides a handy method: [`nextInt(int origin, int bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt-int-int-). Which can then be used in your loop like this:

```
int[][] array = new int[size][size];
ThreadLocalRandom r = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        array[i][j] = r.nextInt(-size, size + 1);
    }
}
```

The first argument `origin` defines from where the numbers should start and the second argument `bound` limits the generated numbers to a given value exclusivly.

Comment: Already upvoted your answer because you added some explanation;)

Answer (score 0):

because round of 1.5 is 2, so in other words supposing random()=1 and size=1 then you have 1*(1+1))-1/2 so (2-1)/2

```
round(1.5)=2
```

instead use .floor(x) method or not use round, as you have casting to int, this should also work (as @Lino pointed out).

Summarizing the result of rounding for 1.5 is 2,
use floor so you will have 1.